# Change an array name in ravendb?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have 3 entities that their relation is like this :

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<StuInfo> StudentInfos { get; set; }
}

public class StuInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string BirthCityName { get; set; }

    public string NationalNo { get; set; }

    public IList<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

in raven db data you can see this schema :

```
{
  "Name": "Hassan",
  "Description": "mike smith",
  "StudentInfos": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "BirthCityName": "berlin",
      "NationalNo": "0064501256",
      "Countries": [
        {
          "CountryId": 1,
          "CountryName": "germany"
        },
        {
          "CountryId": 2,
          "CountryName": "Ghana"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

now I want to rename the countries array to countryList for example , it is an array in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use this feature:
http://ayende.com/blog/157185/awesome-ravendb-feature-of-the-day-evil-patching

Note that you can do that from the studio: 
http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12705/new-option-in-the-ravendb-studiondash-patching

Answer (score 0):

You can either rename your property:

```
public IList<Country> countryList { get; set; }
```

Or tag your property with the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "countryList")]
public IList<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

See [the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/custom-serialization) for further examples.

Comment: My problem is a little different , I know how to rename the property but i don't know how to rename this list's name in student document in raven db, because the student class has a list of stuInfo and this list again has a list of countries , this scenario is like alter table in sql server ,

Answer (score 0):

http://ayende.com/blog/66563/ravendb-migrations-rolling-updates

I have found a post in ayende's site , but i don't know how to use it in code , and i don't know if it works in this scenario or not ?